# concatenate a range with macro, with conditional to omit empty cells - excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concatenate a range of input cells in a column, to one output cell in a separate worksheet.  This is repeated with different ranges to different cells.  e.g. range(A1:5) -> cell(B1) ; range(A6:10) -> cell(B2) ; ...etc.  The output worksheet also needs to be under strict control and hence I would prefer no adjustments to be made to it.

I currently make use of the concatenate formula in the output cell, but I feel it is messy when a cell in the range to be concatenated is empty (the delimiter in the function is a ",").  As an example, there is a possibility that the output cell becomes ",,x,y,,,,z,",etc as a result of empty cells.  I thus need to incorporate a conditional statement into a macro to ignore empty cells, and concatenate the rest with delimiter ",".

An example of desired output would be:  "x,y,z".  **Neat**.

Being a vba amateur and having searched around, all I could find is functions to do this (hence no initial code).  I would prefer a 'button' object so that the user can finalise the process in a controlled way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this *UDF*

```
Public Function concat(rng As Range, sep As String) As String
For Each r In rng
    If concat = "" Then
        concat = r.Value
    Else
        concat = concat & sep & r.Value
    End If
Next
'

End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=concat(A1:Z1,",")

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

With the requirement to **exclude blanks** and use the **comma as a separator**, this would be a reasonable *UDF*

```
Public Function Konkat(rin As Range) As String
    For Each r In rin
        v = r.Value
        If v <> "" Then
            Konkat = Konkat & "," & v
        End If
    Next r
    Konkat = Right(Konkat, Len(Konkat) - 1)
End Function
```

**EDIT#1:**

If the all input cells may be blank, then use this version:

```
Public Function Konkat(rin As Range) As String
    For Each r In rin
        v = r.Value
        If v <> "" Then
            Konkat = Konkat & "," & v
        End If
    Next
    If Konkat = "" Then Exit Function
    Konkat = Right(Konkat, Len(Konkat) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks.  So, are you saying that a UDF is the only possible solution?  If so, that is fine - I will just have to use it.  The output worksheet needs to be under strict control and hence I would prefer no adjustments to be made to it....... formulas or otherwise.  Thanks anyways, very much appreciated.

Comment: @user3740620  It would be REALLY great if the *Concatenate()* worksheet function worked like *Sum()* ............then the *UDF* would not be of help.

Comment: Thanks.  Just one problem though....  I get a "#VALUE!" visible when nothing is entered into the  input cells - i.e. the output cells are #VALUE! by default.  The output concatenates correctly when input is present.  Any idea why #VALUE! is occurring, or how to remove it?

Comment: @user3740620  See my **EDIT#1**  If all the cells are empty then the last statement in the *UDF()* will fail.............so we test for this and leave early!

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student.  I think the reason why #VALUE! is occurring is that there is an 'if' statement in the input cells.... Your solution sorts it out, Thanks!